# Update in MySQL

Tags: mysql

My table is like this: `id, date, url, no`. For example, I have these data:

```
1,2012-01-01,google.com,5
1,2012-01-01,google.ca,3
1,2012-01-02,google.com,8
1,2012-01-02,google.ca,5
2,2012-01-01,google.com,10
2,2012-01-01,google.ca,8
2,2012-01-02,google.com,15
2,2012-01-02,google.ca,12
```

I want to merge the `url`, summate `no`, group by `id,date`, for example, update `google.ca` to `google.com` and remove those `google.ca`. So that the date will be:

```
1,2012-01-01,google.com,8
1,2012-01-02,google.com,13
2,2012-01-01,google.com,18
2,2012-01-02,google.com,27
```

I tried this command but it has error:

```
`UPDATE tb SET no = no + (SELECT no FROM (SELECT id, date, SUM(no) AS no FROM tb WHERE detail = "google.ca" GROUP BY id, date) tb1) WHERE detail = "google.com" AND id = tb1.id AND date = tb1.date
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you need to do? Your example and intended result don't match up with the query you're trying to execute.

Comment: @fuzzyDunlop My query must be wrong. But what I want to do is to add the `no` and update.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t.id, t.date, s.url, SUM(t.no), 
FROM   tb t
LEFT JOIN (SELECT r.id, r.date, r.url FROM tb r WHERE r.no = (SELECT MAX(q.no) FROM q WHERE r.id = q.id AND r.date = q.date)) s ON t.id = s.id AND t.date = s.date
GROUP BY t.id, t.date, s.url
ORDER BY t.id, t.date
```

You don't have to UPDATE the table to get the data you want.  The above does have the issue that you will have multiple rows if there is a tie for `MAX(q.no)`, but I'll let you work that out.

**Edit:**

It sounds like you need to replace the table, basically.  One way, provided that you are sure no other process will need to access any of the tables at the same time (transaction locking is not sufficient here):

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE new_tb (
    id INT,
    date DATE,
    url VARCHAR(whatever),
    no INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (int, date)
);

INSERT new_tb (id, date, url, no)
SELECT t.id, t.date, s.url, SUM(t.no), 
FROM   tb t
LEFT JOIN (SELECT r.id, r.date, r.url FROM tb r WHERE r.no = (SELECT MAX(q.no) FROM q WHERE r.id = q.id AND r.date = q.date)) s ON t.id = s.id AND t.date = s.date
GROUP BY t.id, t.date, s.url
ORDER BY t.id, t.date;

RENAME TABLE tb TO backup_tb;
ALTER TABLE new_tb RENAME tb;
```

For an explanation of the syntax at the end, see the [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/rename-table.html).

**Another edit:**

Can't do things that way?  OK...

```
UPDATE tb SET no = (SELECT SUM(s.no) FROM tb s WHERE s.id = tb.id AND s.date = tb.date)
WHERE  tb.url = 'google.com';
DELETE FROM tb WHERE url = 'google.ca';
```

This suffers from an issue in which, if a `google.com` row is "missing," you would get no results for a particular id and date.

**ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE version:**

I've never used `ON DUPLICATE UPDATE`, but from the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html), maybe the following works:

```
INSERT tb (id, date, url, no)
SELECT s.id, s.date, 'google.com', SUM(s.no)
FROM   tb s
WHERE  s.url = 'google.com' OR s.url = 'google.ca'
GROUP BY s.id, s.date
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE no = VALUES(no);

DELETE FROM tb WHERE s.url = 'google.ca';
```

Comment: @xuc OK, but are you trying to update some rows and delete others?  Your result set does not have as many rows as the input set.

Comment: Yes. My bad. I need to remove the others.

Comment: I cannot do this way. I simplified my question. The actual database is much more complicated, and is huge.

Comment: Actually, `id, date, url` are together the primary key. Is it possible to update `url` (`google.ca` to `google.com`), using ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE?

Comment: @xuc Maybe... I don't have access to a box with MySQL at the moment to try it, but you can see if what I just added will work.